# How to start my service on boot but only with checkbox click

Tags: android, service, checkbox, notifications, sharedpreferences

What I'm trying to do is make it so when you click the checkbox it will start a notification icon, and repeat on boot. And if the checkbox is off, it will kill the notification and won't restart on boot. I have half of this working. (By the way my checkbox is not in an activity, it's in a preference class) Here is the code for it.

```
    CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("quickTweeterSaver");
    checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //preference.setDefaultValue(false);
        //preference.setChecked(true);

          CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) 
          findPreference("quickTweeterSaver"); 
          if(pref != null) { 
             pref.setChecked(false); 
           boolean myValue = (Boolean) newValue;
           if(myValue)
                startService(new Intent(UserSettingsActivity.this, NotifyService.class));
               //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //quickTweetNotification();

           else
               stopService(new Intent(UserSettingsActivity.this, NotifyService.class));
               //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                quitQuickTweetNotification();
          return true;
     }
        return false;
 }; 
    });
```

As you can see I have an if else statement and the first part works, it start's the service and displays the notification (but doesn't keep it on boot) and on the else part, I have to manually call a method to quit the notification icon, because the stop service doesn't work.

So in other words, what I'm trying to make it do is...
-Keep the service on boot when you click the checkbox
-Destroy the service on boot when you unclick the checkbox

Here's my notifiyservice class http://pastebin.com/zgRZpAsF

If you could help me with this, it'd be great. Thanks a lot guys!

*If you need any other info, code, just tell me. I will post immediately!

Comment: What do you mean by "but doesn't keep it on boot"? Do mean that if you start the app it runs as you want but when you shut down the phone and boot up it does not work the same way?

Comment: I mean like, I want it so when you click the checkbox the notification icon still appears when you reboot the phone, and you don't have to manually go and click it again so it turns on. @Mafro34

Comment: Do you have a BroadcastReciever that catches the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast?

Comment: Yes, and I added this in my NotifyService class but when the phone boots it crashes     `@Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "on receive checkbox boot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   //startService(new Intent(NotifyService.this, NotifyService.class));
     }` Here's my manifest entry in the next comment

Comment: `<receiver android:name=".NotifyService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".NotifyService" />`

Comment: I think it is crashing because the your toast is using a context of an activity that is not yet available. try use the context of your Application class.

Answer (score 0):

> Destroy the service on boot when you unclick the checkbox

Use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to disable your `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` if you do not want to get control at boot time.

Comment: i'd also suggest to make this change in the background using AsyncTask, because this is sometimes a bit slow .